# Android ArrayAdapter null object reference

Tags: android

Why I am getting this error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2linux, container, false);

        ListView deviceList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.deviceList);

        updateDeviceList();
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDeviceList);

        deviceList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        deviceList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                openDevice(mDeviceList.get(position));
            }
        });

        startOtgService();

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Any chance you have global ListView declared? Or are you pointing to right listview id which is inside tab2linux layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't find ids in oncreate view method better use onviewcreated method, try using this

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2linux, container, false);


    return view;
}

@Override
 public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

 ListView deviceList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.deviceList);

    updateDeviceList();
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDeviceList);

    deviceList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    deviceList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            openDevice(mDeviceList.get(position));
        }
    });

    startOtgService();

 }
```

Comment: is your listview id correct?, check it once in tab2linux. xml

Comment: It didn't work because I didn't put listView inside tab2linux. xml. Thank you very much Redman

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2linux, container, false);

    ListView deviceList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.deviceList);

    updateDeviceList();
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDeviceList);

    deviceList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    deviceList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            openDevice(mDeviceList.get(position));
        }
    });

    startOtgService();

    return view;
}
```